# Toogle airplane mode in java script for android 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium

I am a python programmer and No experience in Java script, kindly ignore my mistakes even if it seems very basic.

I am trying to use  **toggle-airplane-mode** feature in appium which is only developed for java script.

> ```
> // webdriver.io example
> driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
>
>
>
> // wd example
> await driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
> ```

https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/toggle-airplane-mode/#toggle-airplane-mode

i have already installed

> ```
> npm
> node
> appium
> wd
> ```

i went through internet to find a java script to start a session , and here is what i have written so far

```
let driver = await wd.promiseChainRemote({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4723
});
let desiredCaps = {
  platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '7.0',
    deviceName:'FA67MBN03500',
    automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
    appPackage:'com.htc.contacts',
    appActivity:'com.htc.contacts.DialerTabActivity'
};
await driver.init(desiredCaps);
```

However this runs into error

```
C:\Users\panmishr\Desktop\Appium_test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let driver = await
 wd.promiseChainRemote({

 ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

can anyone please guide me how can i run this script successfully and use the 
**toggleAirplaneMode()**

Comment: Ignore your mistakes or help you get it to run — which one is it?

Comment: @IngoBürk help me to run this!!